# Set Different Timeout for different url in apache httpd conf

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

How to set the Timeout configuration in apache httpd conf to be different for certain URL from the default settings.

I am expecting  something like this

```
    /api/export/download.csv  ->  timeout 600

    /api/getEvents  ->  timeout 400

   /others -> timeout default
```